# VS2012 automatically creates nested css file under sass file and checks out project

Tags: css, visual-studio-2012, sass

I have recently upgraded to VS2012 and have a small issue. All our sass files are checked into source control and the corresponding css file gets generated when the project is built (the css file is never part of source control). with VS2012, as soon as i edit the sass file, a css file is created under the sass file (nested under it) and the project file is checked out. I do not want this as we don't need to check in the css file.

Is there an option i can set to avoid this ? Had a quick look under tools ->options but didnt see anything

The only plugin we have installed is Mindscape Web Workbench free version.

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the Web Workbench plugin was automatically modifying the project file and including the following under my scss files. This was still present even when i disabled and removed the plugin. There's no option to disable this function in Web Workbench, so i wont be using it anymore.

```
  <Compile>True</Compile>
  <Minify>True</Minify>
  <CompileStyle>Nested</CompileStyle>
  <DebugInfo>False</DebugInfo>
```

Using SassyStudio now which is nice and simple.Has the option to disable auto css creation and project adding etc.

Hope this explanation can help someone else.

Comment: Web Essentials (at least 2013 version) has an option to disable auto-compile css